Why does has_one does not work?
So, i am making a escrow contract in solana, using anchor.
I have this accept_job function.
pub fn accept_job(ctx: Context<AcceptJob>) -> Result<()> {
        let escrow_account = &mut ctx.accounts.escrow_account;
        escrow_account.worker_pubkey = *ctx.accounts.worker.key;
        Ok(())
    }

and here is the struct for this
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct AcceptJob<'info> {
    #[account(mut, has_one = client_pubkey)]
    pub escrow_account: Account<'info, EscrowAccount>,
    pub client: Signer<'info>,
    pub worker: Signer<'info>,
}

Now this is the EscrowAccount whose has_one = client_pubkey i am trying to check for
#[account]
pub struct EscrowAccount {
    pub is_initialized: bool,
    pub client_pubkey: Pubkey,
    pub worker_pubkey: Pubkey,
    pub amount: u64,
    pub job_id: String,
    pub bump: u8,
}

But i keep getting this error
error[E0425]: cannot find value `client_pubkey` in this scope
  --> src/lib.rs:76:30
   |
76 |     #[account(mut, has_one = client_pubkey)]
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

Help!!

You need to name the struct fields the same way as you did for instruction fields.
Rename first or the other, e.g.,
// all named as `client`

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct AcceptJob<'info> {
    #[account(mut, has_one = client)]
    pub escrow_account: Account<'info, EscrowAccount>,
    pub client: Signer<'info>,
    pub worker: Signer<'info>,
}

#[account]
pub struct EscrowAccount {
    pub is_initialized: bool,
    pub client: Pubkey,
    pub worker: Pubkey,
    pub amount: u64,
    pub job_id: String,
    pub bump: u8,
}


Hey, thank you.It fixed it.

Feel free to mark the answer as correct one :-)
